# Function defined by an integral.

Tags: real-analysis

Hi everyone: Suppose $f$ is locally integrable on $\mathbb{R}^{N} $, and $B(x,r)$ is  a ball in $\mathbb{R}^{N} $ for each $x$. Intuitvely it is clear that 
$$F(x)=\int_{B(x,r)}f(z)d\lambda(z)$$ is continuous. But how would you prove it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $x \approx y$, then the symmetric difference $B(x, r) \Delta B(y, r)$ is rather small in measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Begin by proving that if $f$ is nonnegative and integrable, then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for any measurable set $E$ with $\lambda(E)<\delta$, $$\int_{A}f<\epsilon.$$
The extension to the non-negative case then follows from taking positive and negative parts, or using the estimate $\int f\leq\int|f|$ and finding the $\delta$ suitable for $|f|$.

The continuity of $F$ follows readily from this, for we have
$$|F(x)-F(y)|=\left|\int_{B(x,r)\Delta B(y,r)}f(z)\;d\lambda(z)\right|\leq\epsilon$$
just as soon as $y$ is sufficiently close to $x$ to insure $\lambda(B(x,r)\Delta B(y,r))\leq\delta$.

It is actually only a small step from the above to prove that (in the one-dimensional case) $F$ is actually *absolutely continuous*, which is sometimes why the lemma in the hint is referred to as the absolute continuity property of the integral.